# "apt-get update" gives an error

Tags: apt, 19.04, mirrors

Currently I updated my OS to 19.04 Disco Dingo, but every time I try to do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it.

Comment: The PPA mentioned doesn't support anything later than 18.04/Bionic.  Did you check it supported disco before adding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom this PPA only contains builds for releases up to 18.04 (Bionic), nothing for 19.04. Therefore you can not use this PPA for your system. Please remove it again, e.g. with

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/atom
```

In their PPA description, they refer to the official Atom documentation for the recommended way to install Atom:

> Please use the official repository instead: https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux

Following that provided link, the official instructions are:

> #### Debian and Ubuntu (deb/apt)
>
> To install Atom on Debian, Ubuntu, or related distributions, add our official
>   package repository to your system by running the following commands:
>
> ```bsh
> wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> You can now install Atom using apt-get (or apt on Ubuntu):
>
> ```bsh
> # Install Atom
> sudo apt-get install atom
> # Install Atom Beta
> sudo apt-get install atom-beta
> ```